# Nested Scroll View Android Studio

Tags: listview, android-studio, android-button, android-nestedscrollview

How can i achieve this design (the yellow arrow) ? and (the orange arrow) ? is it a listview ? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: A yellow is horizontal scrolling or tabs??

Comment: in their application kudos to Paymaya , its a tabs sir

Answer (score 2):

You can use one tablayout and one recyclerview for this purpose.
or you can used NestedScrollView.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_manager_tab_bar_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
       app:tabMode="fixed"
       app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_inactive"
       app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_active"
       app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_active" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/product_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

More first **fragment_manager_tab_bar_tab_layout** display here ***View Card, Scan and Add Money*** and **product_list** you can display Linear Layout **Vertical**.

More full code, you can reference:

https://inducesmile.com/android-tips/android-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview-example/

and this one is also help for your:

http://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Don't Miss this:

https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part2)/

Comment: Thank you so much sir , im gonna try this

Comment: Hi Dharma! Could you answer this question (it's about your Tic-Tac-Toe game):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108298/kotlin-why-to-add-0-while-using-nextint/54109419?noredirect=1#comment95084756_54109419