# Why to add 0 while using nextInt()

Tags: random, kotlin

I am following an instructor creating tic tac toy game, to make it autoplay.

```
var r = Random()
val randInt = r.nextInt(emptyCell.size-0) + 0    // adding 0 here
```

why do we need to add +0 here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why you'd have to write down `+ 0` in that case. `nextInt` returns an `Int`, so adding 0 as an `Int` to it does absolutely nothing - doesn't change the type or affect the value - as you'd expect.

Probably a typo in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `billet` for changing a value if you wish to. Author just showed you where and how to put it to.

Here's how your code should look like:

```
var random = Random()
var randomIndex: Int?
randomIndex = random.nextInt(emptyCell.size - 1) + 2   // two values instead of 00
println("randomIndex $randomIndex")

val emptyCellId = emptyCell[randomIndex]
println("emptyCellId $emptyCellId")

var btnSelect: Button?
btnSelect = setButtonId(noOfCards, emptyCellId)
```

Comment: So why do not we write 
r= random.nextInt(emptyCells.size)
to randomly choose one of the index from there. directly?

Comment: The simplest way to find out it – to ask this question to the author – Dharma Kshetri (you can find him on SO).

Answer (score 0):

Adding 0 will work but it does not change anything.

Note that you are using Java's [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) which would limit your code to the JVM.

If you use [kotlin.random.Random](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html) your code will target all platforms that Kotlin does and would be simpler because you don't need to instantiate a class.

You can use it like this:

```
val randInt = Random.nextInt(emptyCell.size)
```

Check out the [other variants of `nextInt`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/next-int.html) if you don't need to specify bonds or you need to specify an upper bound.